# Solving algebraic fraction problems

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Please could someone help me work out this question for my maths homework

$${\left(a^{16}\right)}^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

($a$ to the power $16$) to the power a half

Comment: You just want to multiply the exponents together.

Comment: use $(a^b)^c = a^{b\cdot c}$.

Comment: $$(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$$ $$(a^{16})^{\frac{1}{2}} \implies a^{16 * \frac{1} {2}}= a^8$$

Answer (score 4):

One of the [properties of exponents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Identities_and_properties) is that $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$, which helps here.